# Spring-data-elasticsearch search for specific fields in multiple indices

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I try to search specific fields in multiple indices. I have two indices `country` and `region`. Both of the indices have a Field called `name`.

I am able to specify my field `name` and my indices in my query using `elasticsaerchTemplate`:

```
@Override
public Page<SearchHit> searchAllTest(String text) {
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(text).field("name"));

    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(queryBuilder)
            .withIndices("region", "country").build();

    ResultsExtractor<Page<SearchHit>> rs = new ResultsExtractor<Page<SearchHit>>() {

        @Override
        public Page<SearchHit> extract(SearchResponse response) {
            List<SearchHit> hits = Arrays.asList(response.getHits().getHits());
            return new PageImpl<SearchHit>(hits, PageRequest.of(0, 10), response.getHits().getTotalHits());
        }

    };
    return elasticsearchTemplate.query(nativeSearchQuery, rs);
}
```

This code works and searches for the field name in both of the indices. But I would like to specify the field `name` in index `region` and give for example a boost.

In simple words:

- Field `name` belongs to index `region` and get a boost.
- Field `name` belongs to index `country` and get no boost.

Is there a way to specify a field for a particular index?

Comment: You can do query time boosting at an index level. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html   Or  index time boosting at a field level, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html (index time boosting is not a recommended practice though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `withIndexBoost` method:

```
NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(queryBuilder)
        .withIndicesBoost(Arrays.asList(new IndexBoost[] {new IndexBoost("region", 2.0f)}))
        .withIndices("region", "country").build();
```